# Transfer file to hololens via POST httprequest (error 429)

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, hololens

I work on a desktop application to communicate with **hololens** glasses via **httprequest** (hololens is connected via USB), especially, I want to read and write files. To do that, I use the following code :

```
class BuildDeployPortal
{
    // Consts
    public static readonly string API_FileQuery = @"http://{0}/api/filesystem/apps/file";

    // Classes & Structs
    public struct ConnectInfo
    {
        public ConnectInfo(string ip, string user, string password)
        {
            IP = ip;
            User = user;
            Password = password;
        }

        public string IP;
        public string User;
        public string Password;
    }

    public async static void GetFile(ConnectInfo connectInfo, string knownfolderid, string filename, string packagefullname, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            // Query
            string query = string.Format(API_FileQuery, connectInfo.IP);
            query += "?knownfolderid=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(knownfolderid);
            query += "&filename=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(filename);
            query += "&packagefullname=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(packagefullname);
            query += "&path=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(path);

            // Create http request
            var httpRequest = new HttpClient();

            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                                                                                        EncodeTo64(connectInfo.User + ":" + connectInfo.Password));

            HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpRequest.GetAsync(query);

            byte[] responseMessage = await resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log some problems
        }

    }



    public async static void UploadFile(ConnectInfo connectInfo, string knownfolderid, string packagefullname, string path, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Query
            string query = string.Format(API_FileQuery, connectInfo.IP);
            query += "?knownfolderid=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(knownfolderid);
            query += "&packagefullname=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(packagefullname);
            query += "&path=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(path);

            //  Create http request
            var httpRequest = new HttpClient();

            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                                                                                        EncodeTo64(connectInfo.User + ":" + connectInfo.Password));
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);

            HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpRequest.PostAsync(query, byteContent);

            var responseMessage = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log some problems
        }

    }


    // Helpers
    private static string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {
        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
        string returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

To run it I call

```
BuildDeployPortal.ConnectInfo co = new BuildDeployPortal.ConnectInfo("127.0.0.1:10080", "user", "pass");

//get file
BuildDeployPortal.GetFile(co, "LocalAppData", "2017-01-25-09-04-21_TestFile.csv", "app_full_package_name", "\\LocalState");

//upload file
BuildDeployPortal.UploadFile(co, "LocalAppData", "app_full_package_name", "\\LocalState",
            "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\info.json");
```

The GetFile method works fine and gives me the file I want but the UploadFile method gives me the following response : StatusCode : 429, ReasonPhrase : 'Too Many Requests'. Same result if I only run one of its during execution.

I don't really understand why I have this error, I just send 1 request (or I'm missing something).

For information, REST API definition can be found [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core).

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same thing.  I've duplicated this code/question to the HoloLens forums: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/8749/transfer-file-to-hololens-via-post-httprequest-error-429  -  but have not seen a response there either.  I'm really hopping this gets solved.

Comment: opps, I see that is your post as well.  I have one a little earlier than that, https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/8736/trying-to-upload-1-files-returns-429-too-many-requests  with out responses.   If you get an answer, please post it up here.  -  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I have no answer, just an alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debugging the issue

The problem is that Chrome 62 sends an empty `content-type` header, while Chrome 61 *did* send the `content-type` header correctly as `multipart/form-data`.

The *cause* is that Microsoft's own code for the FileExplorer.js calls `jQuery.ajax(...)` with `contentType: ""`, so the browser was left to interpret an empty string.

**Excerpt from FileExplorer.js**

```
$.ajax({url:"/api/filesystem/apps/file?"+$.param(r),cache:!1,contentType:"",processData:!1,data:n,type:"post"}).done(...)
```

The [REST API definition you linked from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#upload-a-file) fails to specify any of the Request Headers, and fails to specify the Request Body, so there is no spec against which to determine the correct set of Headers and Body.

FWIW, Microsoft's own [C# Device Portal REST API wrapper](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper/blob/efc4740e1852b0e1e53eec627b67075486b0412a/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper.Shared/HttpRest/RestPost.cs#L54) always sends the content-type header:

```
string contentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundaryString);
```

### The Solution

I have created a bookmarklet that will upload the file correctly when on the FileExplorer page in Device Portal.

#### Expanded Version

```
(function(jQuery) {
var pathLinkData = jQuery(".pathLink:last-child").data(),
    path = pathLinkData.path,
    packagename = pathLinkData.packagename,
    knownfolderid = pathLinkData.knownfolderid,
    url = '/api/filesystem/apps/file?knownfolderid=' + knownfolderid + '&packagefullname=' + packagename + '&path=%5C%5C' + path,
    file_data = jQuery('#fileToUpload')[0].files[0],
    form_data = new FormData();

  form_data.append('file', file_data, file_data.name);

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) { console.error(error) },
    success: function(res){
      alert('uploaded');
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

#### Compact copyable bookmarklet version (also works in inspector/debugger console)

```
javascript:(function(jQuery){var pathLinkData=jQuery('.pathLink:last-child').data(),path=pathLinkData.path,packagename=pathLinkData.packagename,knownfolderid=pathLinkData.knownfolderid,url='/api/filesystem/apps/file?knownfolderid='+knownfolderid+'&packagefullname='+packagename+'&path=%5C%5C'+path,file_data=jQuery('#fileToUpload')[0].files[0],form_data=new FormData();form_data.append('file',file_data,file_data.name);jQuery.ajax({url:url,dataType:'text',cache:false,contentType:false,processData:false,data:form_data,type:'POST',error:function(xhr,textStatus,error){console.error(error)},success:function(res){alert("uploaded");console.log(res);}});})(jQuery);
```

(I have been developing for Hololens for over a year and discovered this as each of my computers separately upgraded to Chrome 62.)

Comment: This is correct - this has been fixed in later versions of Device Portal, but HoloLens has not yet taken the update. To get around this, you can use IE which hasn't been updated and will send a "properly" encoded request.

If there are docs that would help solve this, please let me know and I'll edit the docs on MSDN.

Comment: @HirschSinghal Thanks for the confirmation and inside info.  It would be ideal to have the REST API docs state that `POST` to `/api/filesystem/apps/file` requires a `ContentType` header of `multipart/form-data`, and requires the payload sent as such. (Also there may be a query param required too?) Furthermore, the API responding with 429 Too Many Requests to an empty `ContentType` header could be replaced by a more appropriate status code such as 400 Bad Request or 412 Precondition Failed.

Comment: @HirschSinghal unfortunately, Edge interprets the XHR call the same as Chrome and Firefox and does not correct the content-type from an empty string.  I have added a bookmarklet in my solution that works on Chrome and should work cross-browser.  EDIT:  It would be great if the Device Portal supported JSONP, then I might have been able to use other workarounds. All the object instances and methods in FileExplorer.js are created in closures, so I can't monkey-patch it.  And because the CSRF token is in the cookie/header, plus lack of CORS support from the Device Portal REST API, CORS is out too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really answer to my question (why this error 429 appears) but I give an alternative solution to upload file.

I downloaded [this solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper) to get the WindowsDevicePortalWrapper library.
Then I call the following code to upload file :

```
IDevicePortalConnection connection = new DefaultDevicePortalConnection("http://127.0.0.1:10080", "user", "password");
DevicePortal dp = new DevicePortal(connection);
//write file
await dp.UploadFileAsync("LocalAppData", "C:\\Users\\ng1dd32\\Desktop\\info.json", "\\LocalState", "Lexington_1.0.0.0_x86__ph1m9x8skttmg");
```